# Display IP list attacking my server in Linux (CentOS6)

Tags: linux, security

My goal is to get an accurate list of IPs which are attacking the server, not innocent IPs.
I tried to use

```
netstat -n -p | grep SYN_REC | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

but I'm far from being sure that it displays the list of attackers, and not innocent ips in the same list.
Most of the attack are in layer 7, so http on port 80.
The purpose is to grab the list, copy and paste in a text file, run a batch script and adding `ipset add blacklist` at every lines. Then I can block every attacking IPs in a very short time, using ipset and iptables.

Comment: How do you know that any of the IPs in the list are attackers ?

Comment: This is my question actually. High SYN_REC usually means attacker but looks vague to me.

Comment: Are the attackers hitting a web page ?  If so then grab their IP on the page and save it in a database together with their actions.  Either way I think you need to detect repetitive activity by hooking some applications on the ports you are concerned about.

Comment: Some of the attacks cause MySQL overcharge, so yes they hit a webpage. But recently I've got hit by some huge Layer 7 attack slowing down the traffic to death. Pretty sure it's not hitting a page, but flooding the IP. That's why I'm looking for a solution solid enough to counter both types of attacks. Mitigate myself the attack sounds good but hard to do for a newbe like me. The idea is simple, grab the ips, block these the fastest you can.

Answer (score 1):

What you are essentially describing is making your own Intrusion Detection System, a program that will detect attacks (in this case, a DDOS) and respond appropriately. Generally, you'd want to use a pre-existing tool (if there is one), especially if you are inexperienced with Linux networking/systems administration.

I would recommend that you try using [Snort](https://www.snort.org/), a free, open source, highly customizable, lightweight intrusion detection system. I'd also recommend looking into the [SnortSam plugin](http://www.snortsam.net/), which adds a few friendlier ways of doing what you desire.

Comment: Can I use Snort with DDoS Deflate and APF? I will try it out, thanks a lot.

Comment: You should definitely be able to; Snort can be used to complement the other tools, and to create a more cohesive and dynamic defense.